# Detecting an onfocusout on a text input after focusing

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I'm trying to detect a focusout of an input. First when I click a button it focuses it on the input I want, however when I put the focusout function, the entire script stops working. My syntax is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#editcategorydiv').click(function(){
$('#cardrop').hide();
$('#caredit').show();
$('#categorynme').focus();

$('#categorynme').focusout(
$('#form1').submit();
);

}
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or are there workaround I could use?

Comment: What you mean about "the entire script stops working" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use blur instead of focusout

```
$('#categorynme').on('blur', function () {$('#form1').submit()});
```

and yes, this script is not correct as you can see click function for $('#editcategorydiv')
is not closed, and i guess you also cant use semicolon in focusout form submit. Here is the fixed one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#editcategorydiv').click(function(){
$('#cardrop').hide(); 
$('#caredit').show(); 
$('#categorynme').focus();
$('#categorynme').focusout( $('#form1').submit() );

}); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not noticing the missing code. Yup I tried it and got it working now. Thanks!!